# Android shared preferences for storing data continuously

Tags: android

I'm learning android. I have doubt regarding shared preference file.

I have created a foreground service. The service increments count variable which is initialized with 0.

Whenever the service is destroyed and restarted, the count variable starts from 0 again. But, I want to start it from the previous value. So, I have to store it locally.

Here is the onStartCommand() method.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, displayNotification());

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                //I have to store this count value
                count++;

                sharedPrefEditor.putInt("COUNT_NUMBER", count);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I'm storing count value in the shared preference file.

Is shared preference best in this situation? or is there any better way to do this?

I can make the count variable static and store its value in shared preference file in onDestroy() method, but there is no guarantee that onDestroy() is called.

My requirement is I have to store the count value when the service is destroyed. How to do this?

Comment: You have 3 ways to store your data, SharedPrefrences, DataBase, Cloud DataBase. If you want to store your data in the local storage, both SharedPrefrences and DataBase are good. if you want to make a query, you should initialize a DataBase. If your data is not big, then use SharedPrefrences.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. My actual doubt is, is it ok to write the value in shared preferences every second? Will I face any problem?

Comment: It is not recommended to store values in sharedPrefs that frequently.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: There is no problem to store data in share. but it's not good for big data, we just store data that are not really necessary like, user's phone, logging information, tokens, or something like that. if you want you can have a database (local or cloud) it depends on your data. if data are important, I recommend using a cloud database (something like firebase service) else if your data aren't important, then try to have a local database. (Room database recommended)